# Recovering data from Lacie 500Gb External Drive (2x 250GB IDE internally)

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, lacie

I have some LACIE External HDD's and G-Drives, one of the oldest drives is a 500GB external drive with 2 250GB drives inside of it.

Can i remove these 2 drives and dock them with an IDE type dock and pull the data? the drives were put away when their power adapters failed and i got tired of replacing lacie power adapters.

I do some occasional data recovery for work but nothing of this kind, I was hoping I could run into someone who knew a solution or had the same problem and had a workaround to getting the data off.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention the drives are Mac formatted if that helps at all.

Comment: If they are any type of RAID structure controlled by the LaCie enclosure, I doubt it. I'd check details with LaCie before risking it.

Comment: At US$9 for a Lacie-compatible PS, it might be easier to just replace it: https://www.amazon.com/HQRP-Adapter-External-Adaptor-Supply/dp/B00KFEMO82

Comment: "Can i remove these 2 drives and dock them with an IDE type dock and pull the data?" YES

Comment: @Moab yes but "pulling the data" is totally different from being able to read the data in a meaningful sense, if proprietary RAID is in place.